# The footer of my website's homepage isn't coming

Tags: php, html

I have been trying to make a website. It is an online shopping website.

This is my code-

```
 <?php
    session_start();

    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Books And Beyond</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <!-- Bootstrap styles open source -->
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymus">
    <!-- Customize styles -->
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <!-- font awesome styles open source -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" crossorigin="anonymus">

    <!-- Favicons -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><style 
    type="text/css">
    <!--
    body {
    background-image: url(assets/img/background.jpg);
    }
    -->
    </style></head>
    <body>
    <!-- 
    Upper Header Section 
    -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="topNav">
        <div class="container">
                <div class="alignR">


             <?php if (isset($_SESSION['email'])) { echo $_SESSION['email']; } else { ?>
            <ul class="nav pull-right">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#"><span class="icon-lock"></span> Login <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <form class="form-horizontal loginFrm" action="checkuser.php" method="post">
                  <div class="control-group">
                    <input name="email" type="text" class="span2" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                  </div>
                  <div class="control-group">
                    <input name="password" type="password" class="span2" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                  </div>
                  <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
                    </label>
                    <button name="login" type="submit" class="shopBtn btn-block">Sign in</button>
                  </div>
                </form>
                </div>
                </li>
                </ul>
                <?php } ?>

                <?php if (isset($_SESSION['email'])) { ?> 
                <a href="logout.php"> Logout </a>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <a href="register.php"><span class="icon-edit"></span> Register </a> 
                <?php }?>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--
Lower Header Section 
-->
<div class="container">
<div id="gototop"> </div>
<header id="header">
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4">
    <h1>
    <a class="logo" href="index.php"><span>Books And Beyond</span> 
        <img src="assets/img/logo1.jpg" alt="" width="218" height="94"> </a>    </h1>
    </div>
</div>
</header>

<!--
Navigation Bar Section 
-->
<div class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">

          <div class="nav-collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
              <li class=""><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
              <li class=""><a href="bargain.php">Bargain Books</a></li>
              <li class=""><a href="new.php">New Releases</a></li>
              <li class=""><a href="best.php">Bestsellers</a></li>
              <li class=""><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav pull-right">

            </ul>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
    <img src="assets/img/banner.jpg"/>
      <hr class="soften"/>

    </div>
  </div>
<!--Body Section 
-->
    <div class="row">

<div id="sidebar" class="span3">
<div class="well well-small">
<h3> Category </h3>
    <ul class="nav nav-list">
        <li><a href="fiction.php"><span class="icon-chevron-right"></span>Fiction</a></li>
        <li><a href="nonfiction.php"><span class="icon-chevron-right"></span>Non-Fiction</a></li>
        <li><a href="young.php"><span class="icon-chevron-right"></span>Young Adult</a></li>
        <li><a href="children.php"><span class="icon-chevron-right"></span>Children's</a></li>
        <li><a href="travel.php"><span class="icon-chevron-right"></span>Travel</a></li>
        <li><a href="education.php"><span class="icon-chevron-right"></span>Education</a></li>


        <li style="border:0"> &nbsp;</li>
    </ul>
</div>

            <!--<div class="well well-small alert alert-warning cntr">
                  <h2>50% Discount</h2>
                  <p> 
                     only valid for online order. <br><br><a class="defaultBtn" href="#">Click here </a>
                  </p>
              </div>-->
             <!-- <div class="well well-small" ><a href="#"><img src="assets/img/paypal.jpg" alt="payment method paypal"></a></div>-->

            <!--<a class="shopBtn btn-block" href="#">Upcoming products <br><small>Click to view</small></a>-->

              <ul class="nav nav-list promowrapper">
              <?php

                    /* require_once('dbconnect.php'); */
                    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from product WHERE brand='accessories'");
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
                        { 
                            $intproductid=$row["id"];
                            $price=$row["productprice"];
                            $productimage=$row["productimage"];
                            ?>
            <li>
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img width="200" height="80" src="getImage.php?intproductid=<?php print $intproductid;?>" />
                <div class="caption">
                <table width="250" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="middle"><form action="product_detail.php" method="post" name="form2"  id="form2">
                            <label>
                            <input type="hidden" name="intproductid2" value="<?php echo $intproductid; ?>" />
                            <input name="Submit2" type="submit" class="shopBtn" value="View" />
                            </label>
                </form></td>
    <td align="right" valign="middle"><h4> <span class="pull-right"><?php echo $price; ?>.00</span></h4></td>
  </tr>
</table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li style="border:0"> &nbsp;</li>
            <?php } ?>
          </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="span9">
<!--
New Products
-->
    <div class="well well-small">
    <h3>New Products </h3>
    <hr class="soften"/>
        <div class="row-fluid">
        <div id="newProductcar" class="carousel slide">
            <div class="">
            <div class="item active">
              <ul class="thumbnails">
                          <?php
                    require_once('dbconnect.php');
                    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from product WHERE  brand='bousni'  LIMIT 1");
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
                        { 
                            $intproductid=$row["id"];
                            //$productimage=$row["productimage"];
                            ?>

                <li class="span3">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a href="#" class="tag"></a>
                    <img width="200" height="120" src="getImage.php?intproductid=<?php print $intproductid;?>" />
                </div>
                </li>
                <?php } ?>

                                          <?php
                    require_once('dbconnect.php');
                    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from product WHERE  brand='hela couture'  LIMIT 1");
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
                        { 
                            $intproductid=$row["id"];
                            //$productimage=$row["productimage"];
                            ?>

                <li class="span3">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a href="#" class="tag"></a>
                    <img width="200" height="120" src="getImage.php?intproductid=<?php print $intproductid;?>" />
                </div>
                </li>
                <?php } ?>
                     <?php
                    require_once('dbconnect.php');
                    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from product WHERE  brand='zey'  LIMIT 1");
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
                        { 
                            $intproductid=$row["id"];
                            //$productimage=$row["productimage"];
                            ?>

                <li class="span3">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a href="#" class="tag"></a>
                    <img width="200" height="120" src="getImage.php?intproductid=<?php print $intproductid;?>" />
                </div>
                </li>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php
                    require_once('dbconnect.php');
                    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from product WHERE  brand='AL-JUMAIRA'  LIMIT 1");
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
                        { 
                            $intproductid=$row["id"];
                            //$productimage=$row["productimage"];
                            ?>

                <li class="span3">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a href="#" class="tag"></a>
                    <img width="200" height="120" src="getImage.php?intproductid=<?php print $intproductid;?>" />
                </div>
                </li>
                <?php } ?>
              </ul>
              </div>
           </div>
          </div>
          </div>
          </div>

              <div class="well well-small">
          <div class="span8">
            <div class="row-fluid">

                <h3>Features Products </h3>
                    <hr class="soften"/>

          <ul class="thumbnails">
                        <?php
                    require_once('dbconnect.php');
                    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from product WHERE brand='roza' LIMIT 3");
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
                        { 
                            $intproductid=$row["id"];
                            $productname=$row["productname"];
                            $brand=$row["brand"];
                            $price=$row["productprice"];
                            $productimage=$row["productimage"];
                            ?>

            <li class="span4">
              <div class="thumbnail">

                <img width="250" height="120" src="getImage.php?intproductid=<?php print $intproductid;?>" />
                <div class="caption cntr">
                    <p style="color:#990033"><?php echo $productname; ?></p>
                    <p><?php echo $brand; ?></p>
                    <p><strong>SAR <?php echo $price; ?>.00</strong></p>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="product_detail.php">
                            <label>
                            <input type="hidden" name="intproductid2" value="<?php echo $intproductid; ?>" />
                            <input name="Submit2" type="submit" class="shopBtn" value="View" />
                            <input name="Submit2" type="submit" class="defaultBtn" value="Add to cart" />
                            </label>
                          </form>
         </div>
                    <br class="clr">
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <?php } ?>
          </ul>
          <hr class="soften"/>

          <ul class="thumbnails">
                        <?php
                    require_once('dbconnect.php');
                    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from product WHERE brand='haya' LIMIT 3");
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
                        { 
                            $intproductid=$row["id"];
                            $productname=$row["productname"];
                            $brand=$row["brand"];
                            $price=$row["productprice"];
                            $productimage=$row["productimage"];
                            ?>

            <li class="span4">
              <div class="thumbnail">

                <img width="250" height="120" src="getImage.php?intproductid=<?php print $intproductid;?>" />
                <div class="caption cntr">
                    <p style="color:#990033"><?php echo $productname; ?></p>
                    <p><?php echo $brand; ?></p>
                    <p><strong>SAR <?php echo $price; ?>.00</strong></p>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="product_detail.php">
                            <label>
                            <input type="hidden" name="intproductid2" value="<?php echo $intproductid; ?>" />
                            <input name="Submit2" type="submit" class="shopBtn" value="View" />
                            <input name="Submit2" type="submit" class="defaultBtn" value="Add to cart" />
                            </label>
                          </form>
         </div>
                    <br class="clr">
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <?php } ?>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">

    </div>
</div>
</div></div></div>
<!--
Footer
-->
<footer class="footer" style="float: bottom;">
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span3">
<h5>ORDER SUPPORT</h5>
<a href="contact.php">Store pickup</a><br>
<a href="return.php">Return and Refund</a><br>
 </div>
<div class="span3">
<h5>PRODUCT SUPPORT</h5>
<a href="faqs.php">FAQs</a><br>
<a href="inquiry.php">Inquiry</a><br>
 </div>
<div class="span3">
<h5>COOPORATIVE INFO</h5>
<a href="terms.php">Terms and Condition</a> <br>
<a href="contact.php">Contact us</a><br>
 </div>
<div class="span3">
<h5>GET CONNECTED</h5>
<a href="about.php">About us</a> <br>
<a href="register.php">Create Account</a><br>

 </div>
 </div>
</footer>
</div><!-- /container -->

<div class="copyright">
<div class="container">
    <p class="pull-right">&nbsp;</p>
        <span>Copyright 2019, Fatimatuz Johura - s201403034- Jeddah (Ladies Branch);<br> Books And Beyond</span>

</div>
</div>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.easing-1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.3.1-min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/shop.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The 'New Products' and the footer section is not coming and I cant figure out why. I dont have a webhost yet so I am using localhost for now. I have tried editing the code but whatever I do, it does not seem to work. If anyone can help, I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: My guess is you have a syntax error somewhere in there, it's so hard when PHP and HTML are mixed at this level to tell.  Hence the reason for template engines like `twig` or `blade` etc....

Comment: I think the key would be to view the generated source HTML and see where it stops.  That is likely where your PHP starts to become defective.

Comment: Pasting it in Eclipse PDT, I don't see any syntax errors, although you have 3 variables that are never used.... `$productimage=$row["productimage"]; -- line 159`, `$productimage=$row["productimage"]; -- line 284` and `$productimage=$row["productimage"]; -- line 322`  all the same one which is odd.

Comment: @AaronHolland - that's a great idea, we do have this hint `The 'New Products' and the footer section is not coming` though.

Comment: The best I can figure is you have a DB error, you use this multiple times `require_once('dbconnect.php');` when you only need it once, but the first time you use it is right after the start of `New Products`....  Try turning on Error reporting - `error_reporting(-1);` and `ini_set('display_errors', '1');`  put those right after the `<?php` tag.

Answer (score 0):

On line 152  (new products is on line ~ 185[ish])

```
/* require_once('dbconnect.php'); */
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from product WHERE brand='accessories'");
```

As I said in the comments you use this `require_once('dbconnect.php');` multiple times when it should be only once at the top of your file.

The above code is the first occurrence I could find, and as it's commented out, that query is going to bomb out on you.  Execution happens top to bottom and the first uncommitted occurrence of that is line 196[ish], which is way to late for that first query.

Also as I said in the comments

> Try turning on Error reporting - `error_reporting(-1);` and `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` put those right after the `<?php` tag

You can save yourself, and us a lot of time that way.

**So in Summery,**

Remove all of these `require_once('dbconnect.php');` and then add just one after the opening `<?php` tag.

PS you can easily test this, by just commenting that first query out, or by uncommenting that first `require_once`.

Comment: I tried doing that but the page does not come. I again tried my code(the above code) without removing the 'db connect' codes, and this is what comes in the place of the footer- Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\bab\dbconnect.php:3 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\bab\index.php(153): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\bab\dbconnect.php on line 3

Comment: this is my db connect code. It looks fine to me, and I cant figure out what's wrong with it.                                                                                                   <?php

$db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
//if(!$db) {

//die("Could not connect: " .mysql_error());
//} else {
mysql_select_db('babdb' , $db);

//}

?>

Comment: `Call to undefined function mysql_connect()`  the entire family of `mysql_` functions are removed as of PHP7, so if you want to use them.  You either need to find the `mysql_` extension that is compatable with PHP7, so you can turn them on.  Or you need to downgrade the version of PHP, or better yet use the modern standard like `mysqli_` or `PDO` for database.

Comment: They were removed for various reasons, cheif among them is their lack of Prepared statements and lack of security against SQLInjection attacks.